# Geospatial Queries with Optics API (MarkLogic)

Tags: sparql, marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

Question brought over from [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339286/sparql-geospatial-queries-marklogic/56358334?noredirect=1#comment99359019_56358334).I am currently trying to do a search with SPARQL and CTS using Optics API. I have attempted to try using the following code

Query Used

```
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic" at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
let $people := op:from-lexicons(
  map:entry("people",cts:uri-reference()),
  "lexicon"
)=>op:where(
     cts:path-geospatial-query("people_data/location",
    cts:circle(7500, cts:point(89.39101918779838, 51.97989163203445)),
    "type=long-lat-point")
  )

let $questions := op:from-sparql('SELECT * WHERE {?person </has_dob> ?dob. }', "sparql")

return $questions  => op:join-inner(
    $people,
    op:on(
      op:view-col("lexicon","people"),
      op:view-col("sparql", "person")
    )
  ) => op:result()
```

However, during `op:join-inner` the results returned is empty despite having same entries in both op:result from `$people` and `$questions`. A piece of the results returned can be seen below.

**Results Returned**

lexicon.people

```
{"lexicon.people":"/people/Aaren_DETERS/000000000055933"}
{"lexicon.people":"/people/Aaren_HOWK/000000000117433"}
{"lexicon.people":"/people/Aaren_HUSTEDT/000000000038649"}
{"lexicon.people":"/people/Aaren_SHUSTA/000000000123065"}
{"lexicon.people":"/people/Aaren_SIEBERS/000000000035010"}
{"lexicon.people":"/people/Aarika_BETHARD/000000000048955"}
{"lexicon.people":"/people/Aarika_CHO/000000000093078"}
{"lexicon.people":"/people/Aarika_EVORA/000000000117911"}
{"lexicon.people":"/people/Aarika_LUCKRITZ/000000000001593"}
{"lexicon.people":"/people/Aarika_MCALPHIN/000000000043365"}
{"lexicon.people":"/people/Aarika_PAET/000000000067579"}
{"lexicon.people":"/people/Aarika_SENGUN/000000000047752"}
{"lexicon.people":"/people/Aarika_WEDEMEYER/000000000022594"}
......
```

sparql.person

```
......
{"sparql.person":"/people/Aaren_CRIBLEZ/000000000087536", "sparql.dob":"1999-07-21T00:19:21"}
{"sparql.person":"/people/Aaren_DEBRITO/000000000049208", "sparql.dob":"2018-10-09T08:09:48"}
{"sparql.person":"/people/Aaren_DEMASTERS/000000000091082", "sparql.dob":"2014-08-21T06:43:44"}
{"sparql.person":"/people/Aaren_DETERS/000000000055933", "sparql.dob":"2011-09-11T02:44:22"}
{"sparql.person":"/people/Aaren_GARY/000000000100658", "sparql.dob":"1998-06-04T00:39:23"}
{"sparql.person":"/people/Aaren_HANNAWAY/000000000045087", "sparql.dob":"2002-06-17T05:45:15"}
{"sparql.person":"/people/Aaren_HOWK/000000000117433", "sparql.dob":"2002-06-21T06:00:34"}
{"sparql.person":"/people/Aaren_HUSTEDT/000000000038649", "sparql.dob":"2018-06-07T14:56:39"}
{"sparql.person":"/people/Aaren_JURICH/000000000039301", "sparql.dob":"2003-07-14T16:20:05"}
{"sparql.person":"/people/Aaren_KRACK/000000000101407", "sparql.dob":"2014-03-19T06:25:39"}
{"sparql.person":"/people/Aaren_MACCONNELL/000000000053205", "sparql.dob":"1995-06-21T16:15:53"}
.....
```

I have also done some additional testing where the following code was used to generate a portion of the results using `op:from-sparql`

```
let $query = 'SELECT * WHERE {?person </has_age> ? age . 
                              FILTER(?age > 75)}'
let $questions2 := op:from-sparql($query, "sparql2")
```

Using this result I performed `op:join-inner` and it worked perfectly. This leads me to think that `op:from-lexicons` might be returning a certain data format that is not compatible with `op:from-sparql`? Any clarification or advise will be greatly appreciated.

==Update==

Query used for casting

```
let $questions := op:from-sparql('SELECT * WHERE {?person </has_dob> ?dob. }', "sparql")
                => op:select((  "person", op:as('person_string',fn:string(op:col('person'))) ))
```

==Update 2==

```
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic" at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";
let $people := op:from-lexicons(
  map:entry("people",cts:uri-reference()),
  "lexicon"
)=>op:where(
     cts:path-geospatial-query("people_data/location",
    cts:circle(7500, cts:point(89.39101918779838, 51.97989163203445)),
    "type=long-lat-point")
  )

let $questions := op:from-sparql('SELECT * WHERE {?person </has_dob> ?dob. }', "sparql") 
                => op:select(( "dob", op:as('personStr',ofn:string(op:col('person'))) ))

return $questions  => op:join-inner(
    $people,
    op:on(
      "people","personStr"
    )
  ) => op:select(("personStr","dob")) => op:count("Row Count", "personStr") => op:result()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that the URI lexicon is typed as xs:string and that triple subjects are typically typed as sem:iri.

One way to check would be to use an op:select() on the SPARQL rows with an oxs:string() Optic expression to cast the the subject values to strings prior to the inner join.

If that works, then it might be beneficial to use a TDE template to create the subjects with the xs:string data type instead of the sem:iri data type.

Hoping that helps,

Comment: I have attempted to write the code required for casting which can be found in my updated question. I hope you can have a quick look to see if my approach is correct or wrong. Thank you @ehennum

Comment: That looks like a reasonable way to do the cast.  Just to check, did the test modify the join to use the person_string column with people instead of using person with people?

Comment: Yes I did. However, i encountered an error stating `XDMP-BADCHAR: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected character found '_'`. I assume this is because '_' is not a valid string type? @ehennum

Comment: I have also tries to cast using `xs:string(op:col('person'))` but encountered an error stating `XDMP-CAST: (err:FORG0001) xs:string(op:col('person')) -- Invalid cast: map:map(<map:map xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" .../> cast as xs:string` I have also used `xdmp:type()` to check my `op:result()` from `$people` which results in a many lines of `row` type.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the issue yesterday.  Instead of executing the fn:*() and xs:*() functions immediately on the column identifiers, the expression should import either the ofn or oxs library to execute deferred expression functions on the column values.  See http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/OpticAPI#id_94816

Comment: I finally got it to work after some tweaks with my code and your suggestion. But I would like to ask if it is possible to use `op:count()` without `op:group-by()` as I would like to get the total number of results returned. I attempted to do so by doing `.... => op:select(("personStr","dob")) => op:count("Row Count","personStr") => op:result()` but encountered an error stating `[1.0-ml] XDMP-AS (err:XPTY0004) $options as map:map? -- invalid `. The full code used can be found in my 2nd update

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. The grouping keys in op:group-by() are optional.  If the grouping key is not specified, the row set is a single group and aggregates apply to all rows in the row set. See http://docs.marklogic.com/op:group-by